# asp.net c# - need to get height of datalist rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, height, html, datalist

I've got a datalist in a webpage and, in each row, I've got an image. I'm wanting to stretch the image to the height of each individual row (as the row heights differ) but so far to no avail. Probably doing something completely wrong. Am trying to set it in the C# code behind.

My code (so far) is:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= dlTicksheet.Items.Count - 1; j++)
{
    Image SplitThing = (Image)dlTicksheet.Items[j].FindControl("imgSplit");
    SplitThing.Height = dlTicksheet.Items[j].Height;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is the result of your code?

Comment: The image remains at the same height. I've tried to a Convert.ToInt32 as well, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you don't need to use C#. just add your image as `background-image` as a html tag. and change the `background-size` to `100%`. so it will stretch to the parent container

```
background-size:100%;
```

Comment: This is good, but unfortunately it seems my code is probably too messy for this to be a good idea - unless I'm going it completely wrong. My datalist contains multiple spans, so I may have to try and add it outside of a span.

Comment: Just paste the output html of your code. so we can give you a better guide.

Comment: I *think* I've got it using this. Just need to get it so that it only stays at the right. Needed to define the background-image at the top of the datalist, rather than trying to shoe-horn it into the datalist itself. Will post when I get it working, but thanks.

Comment: I cheated. Basically, it's to add columns into a datalist (the page will be printed and people fill in the columns manually). So I created a graphic with the columns on. Wanted this aligned to the right but not repeating horizontally. Trouble was, taking off the repeat would mean it only appeared once horizontally. So instead I altered the graphic so it stretched across the entire page, but the columns were left in the right. So in other words, I messed around with the graphic until it fit. Code in the aspx - background-image: url('split.bmp'); background-position: right"